# WPF window force redraw window size

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, size

I know there are lots of article over Google related to this, and believe me I have tried almost everything.
So the problem is, I have a wpf application in which when user focuses on any input control like textbox I am showing external touch keyboard using TabTip.exe.
Following code:

```
 public class KeyboardHelper
{
    private const string PROCESS_NAME = "TabTip";
    private const string PROCESS_PATH = "Common Files/Microsoft Shared/ink/TabTip.exe";

    public static void ShowKeyboard()
    {
        Process keyboard = null;
        Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName(PROCESS_NAME);
        if (pname.Length == 0)
        {
            keyboard = new Process();
        }
        else
        {
            keyboard = pname[0];
        }

        string processPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles), PROCESS_PATH);
        keyboard.StartInfo.FileName = processPath;
        keyboard.Start();
    }

    public static void Closekeyboard()
    {
        Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName(PROCESS_NAME);
        if (pname.Length > 0)
        {
            pname[0].Kill();
        }
    }
}
```

Now problem starts here keyboard open but if it is in docked mode, it causes my app to resize almost half of the screen. And when I close the keyboard app remains same in size, I want to restore to full screen state again.
Controlling my size from cs because it comes from a DB

```
WindowState = maximized;
ResizeMode= NoResize;
WindowsStyle = None;
```

Any work around to solve the issue.
I have tried UpdateLayout, Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, Invalidate methods.

Thanks Jason, now I know the cause or can say case scenario of the problem. In my app I have to decide the startup page at runtime, So I am using code like this

```
 private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        //Set startup page for the application.
        MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
        window.ShowDialog();
    }
```

And this is the problem. If I use normal default way than everything works fine.

Comment: Can you add additional detail? I put your code in a new WPF project, created a window (WindowState=Maximized) with a textbox and set the textbox's GotFocus handler to call KeyboardHelper.ShowKeyboard. Regardless of the docking setting of TabTip I couldn't get my application to resize incorrectly.

Comment: as you dock your keyboard, your window resized and both shares the screen. Now when you close keyboard, window remains same half sized, it should regain its original maximized state.

Comment: That is precisely what I am doing. Try running this project and see what happens. http://www.speedyshare.com/9jqTf/KeyboardTest.zip

Comment: You are right its working fine in your code. Let me check again my code.

Comment: Please check update part. I found the issue and tested it on your sample.

Comment: maybe invalidateMeasure? http://stackoverflow.com/q/7289614/73804

Comment: I have already tried all Invalidate methods, UpdateLayout.

Comment: @JasonFry Do you have anything helpful.

Comment: @mayank.karki Even with your latest changes to call Application_Startup I cannot reproduce the issue. Here's my project: http://speedy.sh/NwJbB/KeyboardTest1.zip

Comment: @JasonFry In the latest you provided, there is same problem. As you lose focus keyboard get closed but window not regains maximum.

Comment: @mayank.karki I've tried it on two different machines with the same result (Win 8.1 and Win 7). Can you try it on a different machine?